# Oracle SUM returns false summary with identicals values returing from an SELECT UNION

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sum

I am facing a problem with `SUM` statement.

This query returns `MY_ID = 1` and `QTY = 7`

```
select my_id, sum(qty) qty
from
(     
  select 1 my_id ,2 qty from dual
union
  select 1 my_id, 5 qty from dual
)
group by my_id;
```

But this one returns `MY_ID = 1` and `QTY = 5` instead of `QTY = 10`.

```
select my_id, sum(qty) qty
from
(     
  select 1 my_id ,5 qty from dual
union
  select 1 my_id, 5 qty from dual
)
group by my_id;
```

How can I summary the two quantity in case of the two values **are the same**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use union all:

```
select my_id, sum(qty) qty
from
(     
  select 1 my_id ,5 qty from dual
union all
  select 1 my_id, 5 qty from dual
)
group by my_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using union all:
The below works:

```
select my_id, sum(qty) qty
from
(     
  select 1 my_id ,5 qty from dual
union all
  select 1 my_id, 5 qty from dual
)
group by my_id;
```

this is because 5 union 5 is always 5. if you do union all it includes everything irrespective of it being the same!

Answer (score 1):

In the second query, the two rows in the union are identical.

There are two forms of UNION: UNION ALL and UNION DISTINCT. Which one is the default varies, but it looks like you're getting a UNION DISTINCT, which since the two (1, 5) rows are the same is only returning one of them. Change it to:

```
select my_id, sum(qty) qty
from
(     
  select 1 my_id ,5 qty from dual
union ALL
  select 1 my_id, 5 qty from dual
)
group by my_id;
```

That should give you what you want: (1, 10).

EDIT: Briefly I had union DISTINCT in the query which was wrong! Now corrected....